# Route to two different application on same domain

Tags: apache, nginx, url-routing, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I have about 2000 pages served dynamically on my website.

The structure of the URL is like `example.com/content-x` or `example.com/content-y` i.e. URLs without distinct patterns.

I have got two sites built on two different servers and languages. Each of them serves about 1000 pages. Example. `example.com/content-x` is served from one site where `example.com/content-y` is served from another one.

What's the best way to sever those two applications as one site?

I'm looking at solutions like AWS advance routing where you can configure the load balancer to the server from different servers. But without distinct pattern of URL, I don't see it's easy there.

Can anyone point me which layer is the best to define this kind of rule? Could I do this in the webserver (eg: Nginx) instead? What I'm looking for is to probably have a JSON (or likes) data in a file or any storage and either web server or load balancer to read that configuration and serve the page. Or obviously any other type of solution is most welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could easily do this in application load balancer. the applciation load balancer supports path based routes.

In this scenario, you can have the path `/content-x` pointing to target group x while the path `/content-y` is pointing to target group y.

Each target group could be serving different applications.

Reference:
[How do I achieve path-based routing on an Application Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-achieve-path-based-routing-alb/)

Comment: That's right if I had few URLs to deal with but I have a few thousands. I don't see the above working in that situation. Am I missing anything?

Comment: i missed the 1000 pages part. path based routing also supports patterns like this `/content-x/*` . cant you do this way. any path followed by `/content-x/*` for example `content-y/page1` where as any path followed by `/content-y`goes to site 2

Comment: Unfortunately again, the URLs have no pattern.